# How to call kubernetes pod name in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

I am writing a shell script for executing a pod for which the syntax is:

```
winpty  kubectl --kubeconfig="C:\kubeconfig" -n namespace exec -it podname bash
```

This works fine but since podname is not stable and changes for every deployment so is there any alternative for this?

Thanks.

Comment: you have a deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normally [`$ kubectl exec`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) command but define value for changing pod name.

Assuming that you have deployment and labeled pods: app=example, simply execute:

```
$ kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -l app=example -o custom-columns=:metadata.name) -- bash
```

**EDIT:**

You can also execute:

```
POD_NAME = $(kubectl get pods -l app=example -o custom-columns=":metadata.name")
```

or

```
POD_NAME = $(kubectl get pods -l app=example -o jsonpath = "{. Items [0] .metadata.name}")
```

finally

```
$ winpty kubectl exec -ti $POD_NAME --bash
```

Make sure that you execute command in proper namespace - you can also add `-n` flag and define it.

Comment: What kind on environment you are working ok ? Please show me output of command: kubectl get pods -l app=example -o custom-columns=:metadata.name ? Of course if you have pods label app=exampl (you can use different labels connected with your pod).

Comment: Executing this command gave me the pod name and i am executing this on windows.

Comment: I have edited answer with additional information - take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> exec -it deploy/<deployment-name> -- bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to your application:

As you know, pods are ephemeral; They come in and out of existence dynamically to ensure your application stays in compliance with your configuration. This behavior implements the scaling and self-healing aspects of kubernetes.

You application will consist of one or more pods that are accessible through a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) , The application's service name and address does not change and so acts as the stable interface to reach your application.

This method works both if your application has one pod or many pods.

Does that help?

Comment: I believe OP was referencing a stable name to access a pod via the kubernetes API rather than a normal client coming in